# Acceptance tests with RSPEC, private_pub and Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, resque, private-pub

I'm looking for a bit of guidance on writing acceptance tests for a process that uses Ryan Bates' private_pub gem (https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) and Resque.

In my controller I have an execute action that queues up a file generation process in Resque and then makes an AJAX request to display a "waiting" modal window. The modal window contains the javascript to subscribe to a private_pub channel and wait for a message on that channel. Upon completion of the file generation process in the Resque worker, a message with the newly generated file name is pushed to private_pub. The javascript in the modal receives the message and uses the filename to kick off a download of the file in the browser.

I'm looking for suggestions on techniques to run tests on this process. I've considered mocking the private_pub server (not sure how to even accomplish this after much Googling) so that it simply returns a pre-staged file. Basically I think I need a way to exercise my workflow without the need to run a private_pub server and the whole Resque infrastructure in my test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend stubbing out the call to the Resque worker and simply returning what you'd expect it to return.  Then test the Resque worker code in a separate test.

If your goal is specifically to test the functionality of the modal window, you could write a test that simply makes the call to the Resque worker and use Capybara to determine if the modal shows up.  In this example, you would **not** want to stub the Resque call - simply end the test after you've found the modal window appears.